# NUnit - Running specific test case using testcase attribute through command line

Tags: testing, automation, nunit, testcase

I want to run the below test case through nunit console using command line.`

```
class ListCities : Test.HelperClasses.Testbase
    {
 [TestCase(Category="smoke",TestName = "TC1", Description = "dessciption")]
        public void SearchCity()
        {
        }
   }`
```

I tried the command `--test=Test.HelperClasses.Testbase.ListCities.TC1.`
But i want to execute the test using only testname(TC1) attribute and not along with the `namespace(Test.HelperClasses.Testbase)` and `class name(ListCities)`.

Below is the python code to execute the test case using nunit console

```
os.system("Call "+NunitPath+" "+dllPath+" -- 
test=Test.HelperClasses.Testbase.ListCities.TC1 --result="+resultPath)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `TestName` property of `TestCaseAttribute` only sets the name of the test. The `--test` option of the console runner uses the **full** name of the test. The alternative you tried is the right way to specify this test case - that's how NUnit works.

If you want to have a more succinct syntax, read the documentation for the `--where` option. It would allow you to do something like `--where test=~TC1`.